# Control blender from python script outside of blender

Tags: python, pyside, blender, bpy

i have a GUI made in pyside that render a blender file. This GUI have a resolution options to control this before render scene.... i have this code in PyCharm, i need to run this code without open blender.

[image]

```
    if resolutionWidth != 0:                 
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = resolutionWidth

    if resolutionHeight != 0:
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = resolutionHeight

    # Override Resolution Scale
    #SCALE = batchRender_UI.resolution_scaleUI()
    if SCALE != 0:                      
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = SCALE
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run a blender's python script without opening blender's GUI in background from command line. Go to directory where blender is installed, open terminal/cmd over there and type following command -

`blender -b -P path/to/your/script.py`

The flag -b tells blender to run in background. -P tells to run a python script using blender's python. If you want to open blender's GUI and run py script then run the following code:

```
blender -P path/to/your/script.py
```

While running as subprocess use the following code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['blender', '-b', '-P', 'path/to/your/script.py'])
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me: blender -P path/to/your/script.py. How can I add arguments to my python script?

Comment: Try `blender -P path/to/your/script.py  -- arg0 arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want more interactive control over Blender, you can [build Blender as a python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule).

> This is a build option to be able to import blender into python and access its modules. [...] This is mainly limited to features which can be usable in background mode, so you cant for instance do OpenGL preview renders.

Be aware that since Blender uses a [copyleft license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft), depending on how you want to use and distribute your app, this may or may not be acceptable.